# How many permutations are there at a given Cayley distance from the identity?

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations

Permutations $\sigma$ in the symmetric group $S_n$ can be characterized by their Cayley distance $C_\sigma$, being the minimal number of transpositions needed to convert $\{1,2,3,\ldots n\}$ into $\sigma$. The sign of the permutation is $(-1)^{C_\sigma}$.

<sub>For example, when $\sigma=\{2, 3, 4, 5, 1\}$, one has $C_\sigma=4$ and for $\sigma=\{1, 2, 3, 5, 4\}$ one has $C_\sigma=1$. Of the $5!$ permutations in $S_5$ there are, respectively, $1,10,35,50,24 $ with Cayley distance $C_\sigma=0,1,2,3,4$.</sub>

**Question:** What is the general formula that counts the number of permutations at a given Cayley distance?

<sub>This question was motivated by my attempt to check  [an integral formula](https://mathoverflow.net/a/331312/11260) in the unitary group.</sub>

Comment: https://www.findstat.org/St000216

Comment: @MartinRubey --- wonderful, thank you for the rapid answer; so the number of permutations in $S_n$ at Cayley distance $k\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$ equals $|s_{n,n-k}|$, the Stirling number of the first kind.

Comment: I admit that I (sort of) knew the answer, but I do enjoy pointing out that filling in a handful of values at https://www.findstat.org/StatisticFinder/Permutations is easier than trying to remember!

Comment: you might just enter this in the answer box so that I can accept it...

Comment: It's worth noting that a permutation in $S_n$ with $k$ cycles has Cayley distance $n-k$. This is why Stirling numbers of the first kind appear.

Comment: To be picky, this has nothing to do with the choice of ordering on $\{1,\dots,n\}$ (unlike the standard Coxeter generators).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Cayley distance of a permutation is also known as its absolute length, as can be found out by supplying a few values at 
https://findstat.org/StatisticFinder/Permutations, which yields https://findstat.org/St000216.  There, we also find that for a permutation in $\mathfrak S_n$ with $k$ cycles it is simply $n-k$.  This fact is, for example, Problem 5.6 in [1].

[1] *Petersen, T. Kyle*, [**Eulerian numbers**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4939-3091-3), Birkhäuser Advanced Texts. Basler Lehrbücher. New York, NY: Birkhäuser/Springer (ISBN 978-1-4939-3090-6/hbk; 978-1-4939-3091-3/ebook). xviii, 456 p. (2015). [ZBL1337.05001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1337.05001).